# i need to add a number to a string value in jquery but getting NaN

Tags: jquery

. i have a number abc-13-001 in the database, i want to increase the number by adding 1 to it like, abc-13-002, abc-13-003 etc, When someone click the button, the new increased number will be saved in the value of input_1_9, and in the database, the value will be show in my admin panel. i will have all the code for that, And every time a user submits a form it should increase a the max id like abc-13-001, to abc-13-002 and save it in the value of input and database.

```
 <?php
     $maxValue = "SELECT value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number = '9' ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($maxValue) Or DIE(mysql_error());
$client_id = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $client_id;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function(){
                counter++;
                var result = parseInt("<?php echo  $client_id; ?>") + 1; 
                $("#input_1_9").val(result) ;
                $("#theCount").text(ouput);
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: "abc-13-001" is not a number. You need to extract the part you want to increment instead of trying to handle the whole string.

Comment: What do you get when you alert the `result` variable?

Comment: i want to increase a the number,whenever user click a button, a number will increase like abc-13-000, abc-13-002- abc-13-003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
<?php
     $maxValue = "SELECT value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number = '9' ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1";
    $result = mysql_query($maxValue) Or DIE(mysql_error());
    $client_id = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $client_id_new = explode('-',$client_id);
    $new_value =$client_id_new[0]."-".$client_id_new[1]."-".$client_id_new[2]+1;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function(){
                counter++;
                var result = parseInt("<?php echo $new_value; ?>"); 
                $("#input_1_9").val(result) ;
                $("#theCount").text(ouput);
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not working, i wanna tell one thing also that the increase value abc-13-123 will be first show on the value of input and then saved in the database on click, And i have the code for it also. but the main problem is that i can't increase the number and save it in a value and in database. And then the max value will be from the database next time to increase the number.

Comment: @vbulletinpro: Please check the answer above. Updated it. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The `<?php echo  $client_id; ?>`'s output might be a string, say a PHP Error! So check what it is printing. And also, before you make this call to the `parseInt()`, make sure to check if the particular string is a Number, using `isNum()`.

In your case, `abc-13-001` is not a number. You need to remove the `abc` and the dashes.

Comment: i am not a pro, can you give me example code how it will work, the value from the database is exactly what need like abc-13-001, but i need to increase a number to it, example code will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function(){
                counter++;
                var clientIdStr = "<?php echo  $client_id; ?>";
                var clientidArr = clientIdStr.split("-")
                var clientID = clientidArr[2];                    
                var result = 1+clientID; 
                clientIdStr = clientidArr[0]+clientidArr[1]+result;
                $("#input_1_9").val(clientIdStr) ;
                $("#theCount").text(ouput);
            });

        });
        </script>
```

Check this work for you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not working for me, let me explain you again. i have a number abc-13-001 in the database, i want to increase the number by adding 1 to it like, abc-13-002, abc-13-003 etc, When someone click the button, the new increased number will be saved in the value of input_1_9, and in the database, the value will be show in my admin panel. i will have all the code for that, And every time a user submits a form it should increase a the max id like abc-13-001, and save it in the value of input and database.